# Office UI Fabric DetailsList checkboxes rendered incorrectly on mobile devices

Tags: office-ui-fabric

The Office UI Fabric DetailsList component has an odd behavior when viewed on a mobile device. When you check a selected item in the list, all of the checkboxes suddenly appear (unselected).

**Before selecting:**

[image: Before selecting]

**After selecting:**

[image: After selecting]

You can repro using this codepen: https://codepen.io/elegault/pen/GPwNMQ

Simply open the browser dev tools and select any device from the emulators list, and then toggle on a selection. You'll notice the checkboxes do not all appear when in full browser mode.

I can't find any properties for the DetailsList component that controls this. My component's settings are below.  Is this behavior by design or a bug?

```
        const projects = <Fabric.DetailsList
            items={this.state.items}
            componentRef={this._detailsListRef}
            columns={columns}    
            selectionMode={Fabric.SelectionMode.single}
            selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={true}
            enterModalSelectionOnTouch={true}
            selection={this._selection}
        />;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this simple detailslist example I don't see the same behavior.

https://codepen.io/dzearing/pen/EgqMZq

```
<p>
```

Can you create a reduced test case and then if you still see the problem, submit an issue to https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/

Comment: You're right, yours doesn't repro. I have a different one that doesn't either: https://codepen.io/elegault/full/wQxoRR. Note that my original one doesn't repro in Firefox, but it does in emulator mode on Chrome and in Safari on iOS - please try those.

Comment: Here's a slimmed down repo: https://codepen.io/elegault/full/JxGpQg. Again, view it in Chrome in device emulator mode or in Safari on iOS. The onChange and onSelectionChanged events are not part of the problem as the issue occurs with those events unbound.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has verified that this behavior is by design:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/issues/7808

"The idea is that on a touchscreen device, it shows you the checkboxes so you know what can and can't be selected (contrary to a mouse controlled device where they have the option to hover over a row to see the checkbox visible)."